# Is there a better way to scrape the staff name & email other than this code below?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium to scrape the staff names & emails from this simple html page. However, my code is skipping a lot and return just few data points. I'm not sure why?

I am trying to get all the key data but could not get it all.

I am using Selenium to scrape the staff names & emails from this simple html page. However, my code is skipping a lot and return just few data points. I'm not sure why?

```
################

#   Brick Township High School

# Tuesday, February 7, 2023

################

# imports
import json
from turtle import pd
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
import pandas

# Driver & url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = "https://www.brickschools.org/bths/home-default/departments/#1624628243020-4e557b29-3c1a"  # 1494
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
all_contacts = {}
# contacts = []
fileName_csv = "Brick_teachers.csv"
fileName_json = "Brick_teachers.json"

total_pages = 1

print(f"Total pages as per the website : {total_pages}")
startingPage = 1
endPage = total_pages + 1

# Function to extract info within each contact card

def extract_fields(subject, order, m):
    myXpath = f'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[{subject}]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{order}]/td[{m}]'

    if m == 2:
        myXpath = f'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[{subject}]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{order}]/td[{m}]/a'

    try:
        fieldName = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, myXpath).text
        print("found it", fieldName, ".....", "subject..",
              subject, "order..", order, "m..", m)
    except:
        fieldName = "NA"
    return fieldName



new_contact = {}
for subject in range(1, 13):
    for order in range(2, 20):
        staffName = extract_fields(subject, order, 1)
        staffEmail = extract_fields(subject, order, 2)

        # assign the values to the dictionary
        new_contact['staffName'] = staffName
        new_contact['staffEmail'] = staffEmail

        # add the page number to the dictionary
        new_contact['pageNumber'] = subject
        all_contacts[staffEmail] = new_contact
        new_contact = {}


#### done with data extraction ####

total = len(all_contacts)
print(
    f"We're done with all {total_pages} pages and there are {total} contacts")
# convert the all_contacts to a json file
with open(fileName_json, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(all_contacts, file)

# Step 4 - close the driver
driver.quit()
data = all_contacts

# Convert JSON File to CSV File
# pandas read JSON File
df = pandas.read_json(fileName_json)
df_transposed = df.T
df_transposed.to_csv(fileName_csv)

print(
    "Done! -- with all the pages and JSON & csv files are created")
```

Tried different locators, but it seems that I am missing something!  I am using Selenium to scrape the staff names & emails from this simple html page. However, my code is skipping a lot and return just few data points. I'm not sure why?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML as the site is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have a hard time scraping contact information from that page if you want both names and email addresses. There are at least three different ways contacts are presented in that document, along with a few outliers.

Getting just a list of email address is trivial:

```
matches = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto:")]')
all_emails = set(x.get_attribute("href") for x in matches)
```

For extracting both names and addresses, I came up with something like this:

```
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.brickschools.org/bths/home-default/departments/#1624628243020-4e557b29-3c1a"  # 1494
driver.get(url)
all_contacts = {}

# This is a list of pattern specifications. The "match" key is an XPath
# expression that identifies a top-level element that contains both the name
# and email address. The "name" and "email" keys are callables that when
# evaluated on the matched element return the desired data.
patterns = [
    {
        "match": "//tr[(td/strong) and (td/a[contains(@href, 'mailto:')])]",
        "name": lambda ele: ele.find_element_by_xpath("td/strong").get_attribute(
            "textContent"
        ),
        "email": lambda ele: ele.find_element_by_xpath("td/a").get_attribute("href"),
    },

    {
        "match": "//tr[td/table//a[contains(@href, 'mailto:')]]",
        "name": lambda ele: ele.find_element_by_xpath("td//strong").get_attribute(
            "textContent"
        ),
        "email": lambda ele: ele.find_element_by_xpath("td//td/a").get_attribute(
            "href"
        ),
    },

    {
        "match": "//div[span/a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]]",
        "name": lambda ele: ele.find_element_by_xpath(
            "./preceding-sibling::div[1]/span"
        ).get_attribute("textContent"),
        "email": lambda ele: ele.find_element_by_xpath("span/a").get_attribute("href"),
    },
]

matches = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto:")]')
all_emails = set(x.get_attribute("href") for x in matches)
print(f"expecting {len(all_emails)} contacts")

for patternSpec in patterns:
    matches = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(patternSpec["match"])
    for match in matches:
        try:
            c_name = patternSpec["name"](match)
            c_email = patternSpec["email"](match)
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            # if we fail to process something, just skip it and move on
            continue

        all_contacts[c_name] = c_email

print(f"found {len(all_contacts)} contacts")
print("missing:", all_emails.difference(all_contacts.values()))
```

Running this code produces:

```
expecting 112 contacts
found 110 contacts
missing: {'mailto:cpazmino+FromWWW@...', 'mailto:dstjean+FromWWW@...'}
```

So it works, mostly. Those two outliers are contained inside an
additional `<h5>` element, and we could probably adjust the existing
expression to work with these, but I've run out of steam.

Comment: amazing work! thanks a lot for the effort put in this. Much appreciated :-)